# Akka-HTTP return response in chunks

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am using Akka-HTTP to return a response in form of String [30 - 40 MB].

When I deploy my Akka-HTTP server and make a request to fetch the data from some URI then every time it gets stuck after several MB's and stop fetching the complete response.

Is there any way that I return my whole large response without getting stuck in between.

> HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, entity = myLargeResponseAsString)

Thanks

Comment: Does the "large response" come as a huge string from somewhere outside of your control or are you collecting/concatenating it yourself? Asking since one of the benefits of Akka HTTP is to not have to do that but instead stream data as it arrives.

Comment: I am getting this huge response directly from Apache Solr. Solr is returning this large response in the form of a string.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help:

```
path("yourpath") {
      get {
        complete {
          val str2 = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/tmp/t.log", "UTF8").mkString
          val str = Source.single(ByteString(str2))
          HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity.Chunked.fromData(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, str))
        }
      }
```

Comment: Be sure that you send some payload, with val str = Source.single(ByteString("hello")) works like a charm , at least in Chrome

Comment: Yeah I understand but I am sending 40 mb of data its different scenario

Comment: This code with curl works perfectly reading strings of 300Mb or more without changing the ContentType header. However, browser try to render each 4 MB or 5MB each bunch of data it receives which has no sense. The process is so slow and connection is aborted. To avoid that you must change the header to ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream` and it will create a file with you path .

Comment: Hi Thanks for this but i have to show this on the browser and i am getting this exception on chrome `ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING`
I have also added this conf in application.conf 
include "akka-http-version"
akka.http {
  parsing {
    max-content-length = 50m
    max-chunk-size = 1m
  }
}